# AWS, Can't change ec2 instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My instance is t1.micro on Ireland, eu-west-a1, in a VPC, connected to Elastic IP and a Load Balancer and under Termination Protection. Root device type: EBS, Root device: /dev/sda1

I started with t1.micro but now I want it m3.medium because we are going in production. The problem is that I stopped my instance, Actions -> Change instance type :
and the options that are available are only: t1.micro, m1.small, m1.medium, c1.medium.

Meanwhile on other instances I see that can change the instance type to any options.

What makes this instances different from the others, and how can I solve it

Comment: @aldanux This is a 32bit vs 64bit issue. Using that method will only work for an extra data volume and not the root volume.

Comment: @datasage - Yes.. My mistake..did not think of it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have created the original [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance with a 32-bit image - these are only available for the few instance types you mentioned and can not be upgraded to 64-bit instance types, I'm afraid you need to reinstall on a 64-bit instance type and migrate your data across.

- See e.g. RakeshS' answer to [How can I upgrade my 32 bit Amazon EC2 EBS backed instance into 64 bit one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407400/45773) for high level instructions how to manually migrate you data to a fresh 64-bit instance.

Please note that AWS has introduced *64-bit Ubiquity* in spring 2012, i.e. every instance type can be used with 64-bit images, which (as you just painfully discovered) *will make it easier for you to scale vertically (to larger and smaller instances) without having to maintain parallel (32 and 64-bit) AMIs* indeed (see [EC2 Updates: New Medium Instance, 64-bit Ubiquity, SSH Client](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/ec2-updates-new-instance-64-bit-bit-ubiquity-ssh-client.html) for details).

I strongly agree with Eric Hammond's advise to only [Use the Same Architecture (64-bit) on All EC2 Instance Types](http://alestic.com/2012/03/ec2-64-bit) going forward:

> Though t1.micro, m1.small, and c1.medium will continue to also support
>   32-bit AMIs, it is my opinion that there is virtually no reason to use
>   32-bit instances on EC2 any more.
>
> This is fantastic news!
>
> Sticking with 64-bit instances everywhere all the time gives you the
>   most flexibility to [switch the instance type of your running
>   instances](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-change-type), reduces the choices and work necessary when building your
>   own AMIs, and just makes life simpler.