# AWS EC2 can't change instance type - greyed out or disabled option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The instance is stopped, it's a VPC instance (not classic), and it has an EBS volume. Linux2 AMI. For some reason the instance type is not able to be modified. I need to upgrade the instance type from a t2.micro to a t2.small or t2.medium.

Saw this question that seems to be similar ,but I don't know how to tell if the instance is 32-bit or 64-bit image.

[AWS, Can't change ec2 instance type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614380/aws-cant-change-ec2-instance-type)

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 only supports 64 bits, so you have 64 bit image. What about other instance types? Maybe at present the types you want are not avaiabile?

Comment: But the option to change the instance type is greyed out, it won't even let me see what other types are available.

Comment: Can you provide details of your AMI? Its difficult to speculate without any info of what you are running.

Comment: Not sure what info would be helpful. The AMI name is amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20210318.0-x86_64-gp2. It's on an elastic IP.

Comment: Are you sure the instance is stopped? Also did you refresh your browser after sopping it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem in the future, after hearing back from AWS support, the reason I couldn't modify the instance type was because hibernation mode was enabled, which I guess prevents you from modifying the instance type.

Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
In the navigation pane, choose Instances.
Select the instance and, on the Details tab, in the Instance details section, inspect Stop-hibernate behavior. Enabled indicates that the instance is enabled for hibernation.

Please be informed that as per the requirement to Change the instance type, You can't change the instance type or size of an instance with hibernation enabled.

```
    [+] Change the instance type: Requirements :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#resize-requirements
```

It is because of the hibernation enabled on your instance, You are unable to change instance type for 'i-0de6056502fec7de9’ and the option in the console is greyed out. In addition, as per design of the service you can't enable or disable hibernation for an instance after you launch it.

```
    [+] Enable hibernation for an instance :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Hibernate.html#enabling-hibernation
```

Further, you will need to recreate this instance in order to resize it to your needs. As one of the limitations of instance hibernation is that If you create a snapshot or AMI from an instance that is hibernated or has hibernation enabled, you might not be able to connect to the instance.

```
    [+] Hibernation Limitations :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Hibernate.html#hibernating-not-supported
```

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected it, but this confirms it.  I had wondered why hibernation was not enabled by default.  Still doesn't make sense, but oh well...

Answer (score 22):

You cannot change instance type if

1. Your instance is running.
   Solution: Stop your instance (Don't terminate).  Then Actions button -> Instance settings -> Change instance type.
2. Your instance hibernation is enabled.
   Solution: You cannot disable hibernation after you launched your instance.  You need to go to Management Console -> Select your instance -> Actions button -> Image and templates -> Create image.  Then on the left hand side menu -> Images -> AMI -> Select your image -> Launch -> start a new instance type.
3. [You can't change the instance type of a Spot instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20change%20the%20instance%20type%20of%20a%20Spot%20Instance.) (exception: as of 2020, spot instances that are part of a [spot fleet can change their instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-ec2-spot-fleet-support-modifying-instance-types-weights-on-run/)).

   a. if you try to stop a Spot instance, you would get the following error

   ```
   Failed to stop the instance instance id
   You can't stop the Spot Instance 'instance id' because it is associated with a one-time Spot Instance request. You can only stop Spot Instances associated with persistent Spot Instance requests.
   ```

   b. That being said, if your spot instance is a *persistent* spot instance, you can use the [EC2 Spot Converter](https://github.com/jcjorel/ec2-spot-converter) tool, an open source project on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change your instance type if:

- hibernation is enabled
- it is a spot instance

You also cannot change to another processor's architecture and few other cases, please find all about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#change-instance-type-of-ebs-backed-instance) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/resize-limitations.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, although my instance is shown in "Stopped" state, it seems it's not stopped completely.

After I wait for another 5~10 minutes, it then allows me to change the instance type.

Comment: it's true, in my case, I logout and login to aws console again and it shows all instance types.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to see the current instance in the options and didn't have any of the above mentioned issues. A hard page refresh made the options show up `cmd + shift + R`.